# Grails g:remoteLink response

Tags: grails

How can I get the response from an ajax call made with g:remoteLink, using jquery ?

I have tried using  `nSuccess="removeTask(e)"` and getting the response with e.responseText or e.response, but nothing works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using Grails with the JQuery plug in and using the remote functions like remoteLink, the code that is generated for the remote function is something like this:

```
success: function(data, textStatus){ jQuery('#results').html(data); }
```

This is if for example you set the update parameter as "[success:'results']". As you can see the main function receives a data parameter which I think is what your looking for, so if you need to call another function that uses that value, you could do something like this:

```
<g:remoteLink controller="yourcontroller" action="youraction" update="[success: 'results']" onSuccess="yourFunction(data) ">Your link</g:remoteLink>
```

This will generate javascript code like this:

```
success:function(data,textStatus){ jQuery('#results').html(data); yourFunction(data); }
```

Hope this helps!!