# How to get the data from the controller by periodically calling remoteFunction?

Tags: javascript, grails

This is the situation:

I have a file with information updated each 30 seconds. I have created a method that reads the file and extracts needed data. In the controller, let say `RefreshController`, I have a method  `ref` that is called each 30 seconds:

```
def ref = {
    def Helper h = new Helper()
    def d = JSON.parse(h.readFile())
    render(view: 'index', model: [data: d])
}
```

by grails `remoteFunction`:

```
<g:javascript>
setInterval(refreshMe, 30000);
function refreshMe(){
    ${remoteFunction(controller: 'refresh', action: 'ref', onSuccess: 'justDoIt(e);')}
}
function justDoIt(e){
    alert('hello'); // to create the table on the fly, but missing the data from the controller
}</g:javascript>
```

The question is, how to get or how to access the refreshed data from the controller into the javascript function? I can access the `${data}`, but in that case I only get the first, initialized value of the `data` variable in the controller.

I would like to use refreshed data to create a table on the fly and not on already existing elements.

I would appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057266/grails-gremotelink-response

Comment: @tomas Thanks your pointing out, but it doesn't help. I don't have a problem by calling remoteFunction/remoteLink once. I need to do it every 30 secs, for which, I guess, the remoteFunction should be in the javascript code.  However, I don't get anything in 'data' parameter, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

On your controller just render your json result instead of the view, look at the example below, when you render the view your data object will be your view. Also onSuccess has data parameter. Hope this helps

```
class RefreshController {

def index() { }

def ref () {
    println params
    def json = new JsonBuilder()
    json.state
    {
        name "Colorado"
        statehood 1876
        capital "Denver"
        majorCities "Denver", "Colorado Springs", "Fort Collins"
    }

    render json
}
```

}

View :

```
    <!doctype html>
<%@ page import="com.package.example.*" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<r:require modules="jquery"/>
<r:script>
   function refreshMe(){
    //alert("refresh js")
        ${remoteFunction(controller: 'refresh', action: 'ref', onSuccess: 'justDoIt(data,textStatus);')}
    }
    function justDoIt(data,textStatus){
        alert(responsData+" "+textStatus); 
    }
</r:script>

</head>

<body>
<a href="javascript:refreshMe();">Link text</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Alidad! Indeed, your idea is closest to the solution that I've found. I provide it below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

Controller:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
class RefreshController {
   def index = {}
   def ref= {
      def d = getString()
      render d as JSON
   }
   String getString(){
   // ...
   }
}
```

View:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Power In Use</title>
<meta name="layout" content="main" />
<g:javascript library="prototype"/>
</head>
<body>
<g:javascript >
  setInterval( "refreshMe();", 30000 );
  function refreshMe(){
      ${remoteFunction(action:'ref', controller:'refresh', onSuccess: 'makeTable(e)')}
  }
  function makeTable(e){    
  var d = e.responseText.evalJSON(true);
  // do something with data d
  }
</g:javascript>
</body>
</html>
```